# single template function to display contents of different container

Tags: c++, list, templates, vector, deque

I have a vector container constructed using:

```
vector<int> v1;
v1.push_back(1);
v1.push_back(2);
v1.push_back(3);
```

And deque container constructed using:

```
deque<int> deq;
deq.push_front(1);
deq.push_front(2);
deq.push_front(3);
```

I want to have a template function that displays the content of the both of these containers and for all data-types. For handling with different data types I made a template function like this:

```
template <typename T>
void display(vector<T> vec)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Currently its working for vector, How can I make it work for all containers like deque, and list?

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename C>
void display(const C& container) {
  std::copy(std::begin(container), std::end(container),
    std::ostream_iterator<decltype(*std::begin(container))>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: why `decltype(*std::begin(container))` instead of  `typename C::value_type`?

Comment: @Caleth Why not? Fewer requirements on `C` this way.

Comment: Won't this invoke a copy constructor for each element of container?

Comment: @jschultz410 it won't see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator%3D  the assignment to an `ostream_iterator` accepts the value by const reference

Comment: @Curious: I see.  I guess I shouldn't assume std::copy means what its name implies.  It probably should have been named std::assign or std::set_eq instead ...

Comment: @jschultz410 I feel like `ostream_iterator` is a hack on top of `std::copy` rather than `std::copy` not being general in what it does personally

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might use range-based for-loop:

```
template<typename C>
void display(const C& container)
{
    for (const auto& e : container)
    {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many STL containers support ranges with pairs as value types so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

namespace detail {
    template <typename First, typename Second>
    void print_element(const std::pair<First, Second>& pr) {
        cout << pr.first << " " << pr.second << endl;
    }

    template <typename Type>
    void print_element(const Type& element) {
        cout << element << endl;
    }
} // namespace detail

template <typename Container>
void print_all(const Container& container) {
    for (const auto& element : container) {
        detail::print_element(element);
    }
}


int main() {

    auto v = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
    auto d = std::deque<int>{1, 2, 3};
    auto m = std::map<int, int>{{1, 2}};
    print_all(v);
    print_all(d);
    print_all(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Curious, I'm curious (sorry couldn't help it), why are you making a special case only for std::pair?

Comment: @jschultz410 because many containers like `std::unordered_map` and `std::map` have `std::pair` as the value types when you iterate with their iterators.  Is there any other value wrapper that STL containers used that I missed taking into consideration?

Comment: I guess if you wanted to be more general you'd specialize for std::tuple.  My point was that there are probably all sorts of types that don't have an output operator.  I was just wondering why you singled out std::pair for special treatment.  I guess because it is a common type in the standard library is a good reason.